# How to Dynamic create and remove a tabs in foundation 6?

Tags: jquery, tabs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I want to make user to click for example add button in the tab section to dynamically create the content of the second tab base on what is in the first tab.

I achieve this in Bootstrap but i'm really stuck with this one in foundation.

Can someone please help here.
Thank you in advance

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="tabs main-tab nav-tabs" data-tabs id="shop-main-tabs">

     <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#info1" aria-selected="true" ><i class="fi-torso"> Add Participant</i></a></li>

     <li class="tabs-title main-tab" ><a href="#" class="add-form"><i class="fi-plus">+</i></a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMOGyO

How to achieve this in foundation.

Comment: So you just want the "+" button to create a new tab with empty fields?

Comment: @Yass i want it to create a new tab plus the form in the first tab content. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is only adding the tab heading. In your `.add-form` `click` event you need to add a corresponding div for the tab content.

The line below uses the `html` content from the first tab and `appends` it to a new `div`, which is added to `.tabs-content`. It uses `tabId` to ensure it's associated with the correct tab heading:

```
$(".tabs-content").append('<div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="' + tabId + '">' + $("#info1").html() + '</div>');
```

I'm also calling `$(document).foundation();` after adding the new content to ensure any **event listeners** are rebound.

The Foundation 6 docs don't provide nearly enough information when it comes to programmatically selecting tabs, but I've come up with a solution after a bit of trial and error.

I had to remove the `tabs-title` class from the "+" button as it interferes with the tab selection. You'll have to re-style it using a different class name.

```
//Find the parent "ul" that contains the tabs
var target = document.getElementById("shop-main-tabs");
var options = {
    "linkClass": "tabs-title"
};

//Use the target "ul" to initialize the "Tabs" object.
var elem = new Foundation.Tabs($(target), options);

//Find the tab that will be selected
var tab = document.getElementById(tabId);
elem.selectTab($(tab));
```

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXbmwB)**

Comment: Thank you so much. How can i make the newly created tab be active? Also is it possible to limited it to for example only allow to create only 5 tabs?

Comment: You need to set the is-active class on the new tab. I'm not at my pc atm so I can't test.

Comment: I do just that but it is still making the + active. Please take a look at it for me when you get to your desk. Thank you so much Yass, i really appreciate your help. here is the updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVRVEp

Comment: @Builda Please see my updated answer for a solution. I've had to make some changes to how the "+" button `click` event works and I've also removed the `tabs-title` class.

Comment: Awesome sauce. Thank you so much @Yass. I wish i can give a vote but i don't have enough reputation. From the bottom of my heart. Thank you. This solve the problem

Comment: No probs. Please consider accepting my answer, thanks.